# Credstash: 'module' object has no attribute 'get': AttributeError

Tags: python-2.7, aws-lambda, credstash

I am trying to use credstash for accessing credentials stored in KMS, however, even before accessing them, the python 2.7 lambda runtime on aws is giving me an error:

```
'module' object has no attribute 'get': AttributeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 12, in lambda_handler
    print '%s' %(credstash.get('tv.forecaster.dev.cms.username'))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get'
```

As there is hardly any info out there, i am struggling with this problem in vain. If anyone can help me solve the problem, I will be highly grateful. Following is my requirements.txt:

```
credstash==1.13.1
cryptography==2.0.3
```

I am accessing my credentials like this:

```
import credstash

string cred = credstash.get('name_of_the_stored_cred_in_dynamodb')
```

is the way i am accessing the credential using credstash wrong?

Comment: do you have a file called `credstash.py` in your project root or in the zip file you're uploading to lambda?

Comment: @hansaplast no, it was in the root of the zip file. However, I realized the error when i read the source code of credstash.py. Basically it is credstash.getSecret('name_of_cred') and not .get(). It worked magically thereafter. Also, I had to package it on a amazon linux container instead of mac.

Comment: can you put that as an answer to your own question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized the error when i read the source code of credstash.py. Basically it is `credstash.getSecret('name_of_cred')` and not `.get()`. It worked magically thereafter. Also, I had to package it on a amazon linux container instead of mac